# Jquery dropline menu in dropdown partialy

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, drop-down-menu

Is somehow possible to change behaviour of 
[this dropline menu](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/jquery_drop_line_menu/) to act as it, but third level to act as a dropdown insted of dropline.

tnx

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the superfish example, either use that one or see the css they use to have the 3rd level be a dropdown

http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#sample4